# Practical use of 'protected' specifier in C++

Tags: c++, protected

I know how this specifier works.

I'm interested in practical usage of this stuff in real programming.  I can't imagine any example where protected class members are really necessary (I mean when we can not to replace 'protected' with 'private').

Comment: You may be hurting your question by asking when it is *really necessary*.  The entire C++ language isn't *really neccessary*.  Are you asking when it is useful?

Comment: I think I'd take a step back. When/if you use inheritance, the use for protected seems fairly obvious (at least to me). IMO, the real question is: "What are the practical uses of inheritance in C++?"

Comment: @JerryCoffin if it really obvious, where and when can't I replace 'protected' with 'private' or 'public'? (depends on a situation)

Comment: @mechanic: For the most obvious example, a function that's both private and virtual is almost impossible to justify.

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed. This is a very excellent question for those learning object oriented programming. By the comments, it looks as though the question has undergone some reformatting to appease some of our more pedantic S.O. members. I think the intent of the question is clear, and valuable to newer programmers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A class has two APIs - one for code that instantiates it and uses the resulting objects, and one for subclasses.

The first API is the `public` members, while the second is the `public` and `protected` members.  There are operations and data that it's OK for a subclass to access that it isn't OK for "ordinary users" to access.

As a concrete example, imagine a Windows GUI class library.  It wraps and hides the plain old Windows API.  A `Window` represents a window, and has an `HWND` which is the underlying Windows window handle.  It hides the `HWND` from users of the `Window` class, because it's none of their business (or if it's OK for them to use it, it only exposes it via a read-only accessor).  But it's OK for subclasses of `Window`, like `FrameWindow` or  `EditControl`, to access the `HWND` directly:

```
class Window
{
public:
    void Show();  // Example public API

protected:
    HWND m_hwnd;
};
```

Comment: I like the term "two APIs". All of this is especially true in designing a reusable framework.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: There are actually *three* API's :) the public for clients, the protected where you offer services to your derived types and the virtual through which your base obtains services from the derived types. You can google for NVI (NonVirtual Interface) that discusses how to design for the public and virtual interfaces +1

Comment: Lately, I've seen a preference for only setting non-public methods, virtual and otherwise, as protected, but always forcing data members to be private.  Generally, I find that usable, and useful when designing the class hierarchy; but sometimes it makes more sense for the data to be protected - for instance, if the datum is a functor.